# how do i add a space to my switch statement output?

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm making a caesar cipher program in java. I used the switch statement and I only have one problem is when I write my full name there will be no space between my first and last.

```
import java.util.*;

public class caesarCipher {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write your name:");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("The Encryption for your name:");

        for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {

            switch (name.charAt(i)) {
                case 'A':
                case 'a':
                    System.out.print("E");
                    break;
                case 'B':
                case 'b':
                    System.out.print("Y");
                    break;
                case 'C':
                case 'c':
                    System.out.print("F");
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'd':
                    System.out.print("Q");
                    break;
                case 'E':
                case 'e':
                    System.out.print("W");
                    break;
                case 'F':
                case 'f':
                    System.out.print("D");
                    break;
                case 'G':
                case 'g':
                    System.out.print("T");
                    break;
                case 'H':
                case 'h':
                    System.out.print("C");
                    break;
                case 'I':
                case 'i':
                    System.out.print("R");
                    break;
                case 'J':
                case 'j':
                    System.out.print("N");
                    break;
                case 'K':
                case 'k':
                    System.out.print("B");
                    break;
                case 'L':
                case 'l':
                    System.out.print("G");
                    break;
                case 'M':
                case 'm':
                    System.out.print("A");
                    break;
                case 'N':
                case 'n':
                    System.out.print("J");
                    break;
                case 'O':
                case 'o':
                    System.out.print("X");
                    break;
                case 'P':
                case 'p':
                    System.out.print("O");
                    break;
                case 'Q':
                case 'q':
                    System.out.print("I");
                    break;
                case 'R':
                case 'r':
                    System.out.print("L");
                    break;
                case 'S':
                case 's':
                    System.out.print("Z");
                    break;
                case 'T':
                case 't':
                    System.out.print("M");
                    break;
                case 'U':
                case 'u':
                    System.out.print("P");
                    break;
                case 'V':
                case 'v':
                    System.out.print("S");
                    break;
                case 'W':
                case 'w':
                    System.out.print("H");
                    break;
                case 'X':
                case 'x':
                    System.out.print("K");
                    break;
                case 'Y':
                case 'y':
                    System.out.print("V");
                    break;
                case 'Z':
                case 'z':
                    System.out.print("U");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I bet that copy/pasting was really painful.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a `case` for every letter but not for a space, it will just get dropped during your encryption process. You could add a `default` at the end of the `switch` statement that just outputs the letter without encrypting it. This would then catch the space as well.

```
// ...
case 'Z': 
case 'z': 
    System.out.print("U");
    break;
default: 
    System.out.print(name.charAt(i));
    break;
```

Comment: This is actually a really elegant way to do it.

Comment: I up voted but I would not do a default case I would just do a space case cause you don't know what should be the behavior for punctuations and other symbols. potential altering the the behavior with side effects.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use a default case to handle a space, because then all other symbols you haven't handled would be represented by a space.

Simply continue your same method of handling characters:

```
case ' ':  
    System.out.print(" ");
    break;
```